# Localization exceptions when trying to have multilanguage forms

Tags: .net, visual-c++, localization, managed

I have made two forms that upon starting will check on a flag, if flag is, for example, set to true, it would open the forms in french. Else it would open the forms in default language (english). As I try to run the code I get this error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "AMSIMOD.SelectVariableForm.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Wood_Quality" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

I tried searching a bit on my own, knowing that visual c++ is very similar to c#, but I have no clue what to look for and or the answers I find (all c#) seems to use a run custom tools which my visual studio doesn't seem to have. I have, at this, point no clue what I'm doing

What does this error mean? I am new to ressource files managing (and visual c++) a complete noob in c# so I am completely lost. Thanks

Comment: Can you give more information about your project. Is it C++ or C#? If C++, is it managed of unmanaged code (for example MFC)? Are you using .rc files or .resx files.

Comment: it is a c++ project, and I believe the files created were resx files.

Comment: So as I mentionned couple days ago, this is managed visual c++. I've tried doing some research on satelitte assemblies but only get c# which in this case seems very different thant c++

Comment: Try searching for "using resx in C++". I found multiple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187772/how-can-unmanaged-c-use-a-resx-file), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398407/can-c-cli-net-use-resource-resx-files-for-localization), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070451/resx-files-for-localization-with-managed-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282461/why-cant-i-load-an-image-resource-from-my-resx-file). I think one of them should help you.